# How to load and display a S 57 file in pyqgis standalone application

Tags: python, python-3.x, qgis

I need to display a S 57 file using pyqgis 3 What I have done so far is that I have created a QT window and I am trying to load a S 57 file in it with code below

```
QMainWindow.__init__(self)
# Required by Qt4 to initialize the UI
self.setupUi(self)
# Set the title for the app
self.setWindowTitle("ShapeViewer")
# Create the map canvas
self.canvas = QgsMapCanvas()
# self.canvas.useImageToRender(False)
self.canvas.show()
# Lay our widgets out in the main window using a
# vertical box layout
self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self.frame)
self.layout.addWidget(self.canvas)
# layout is set – open a layer
#  Add an OGR layer to the map

file = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open S57file", ".", "S57files (*.000)")
fileInfo = QFileInfo(file[0])
# Add the layer
layer = QgsVectorLayer(file[0], fileInfo.fileName(), "ogr")

if not layer.isValid():
    print("Invalid Layer File")
    return


QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer);   
self.canvas.setExtent(layer.extent())
```

layer is valid but the windows is showing blank frame and same S-57 is displaying fine in different softwares correctly.